# How to stop audio file and automatically play next file in expo app in react native?

Tags: react-native, audio, expo

I am testing my react native app on my iPhone with Expo audio and am having some issues.

I have multiple audio files here:

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);

this.sets = [
    {
        'name': 'Get started', 
        'image': 'https://media2.giphy.com/media/L3txcnbi3ODhV8XbcC/giphy.gif?cid=ecf05e4753ab0311a208263dfa2f06b292304586b6968cd5&rid=giphy.gif',
        'audio_file': 'https://www.buzzsprout.com/919750/2968663-rowing-test-2.mp3'
    },
    {
        'name': '5 pushups', 
        'image': 'https://media3.giphy.com/media/3ohze1qkqPZHMrEuwo/giphy.gif?cid=ecf05e477ee256ccf5c259848c5d44eb07cea572a4b05e29&rid=giphy.gif',
        'audio_file': 'https://www.buzzsprout.com/919750/2946361.mp3'
    },
    {
        'name': '10 burpees', 
        'image': 'https://media1.giphy.com/media/23hPPMRgPxbNBlPQe3/giphy.gif?cid=ecf05e476831df96aaeea2281fa09fb198d9ca8b14f8405c&rid=giphy.gif',
        'audio_file': 'https://www.buzzsprout.com/919750/2946361.mp3'
    }
]

this.state = {
    index: 0,
    isPlaying: false,
    playbackInstance: null,
    currentIndex: 0,
    volume: 1.0,
    isBuffering: false,
    value:0,
    isLooping: true
}
}
```

I have a play button that should play the current file. When pressed, the pause button shows and then pauses the audio file. This functionality works fine.

However, I also want the user to be able to go to the next track. When the user presses the next button, I'd like for the current audio to stop, go to the next track, and start the track immediately. I am having trouble doing this. Currently what happens is I hit next, the same audio continues to play and then when I press play again, the next audio file plays on top of the original file. How do I address this?

```
nextWorkout = async () => {



        const { isPlaying, playbackInstance } = this.state


        isPlaying
          ? await playbackInstance.pauseAsync()
          : await playbackInstance.playAsync()

        // go to next track
        this.setState({
          isPlaying: !isPlaying,
          index:this.state.index + 1
        })

        // load next audio file
        this.loadAudio()
            .then(playbackInstance.playAsync());

        // play next audio file
        // playbackInstance.playAsync();

        // scroll to image in horizontal flatlist
        // this.flatListRef.scrollToIndex({animated: true, index: this.state.index});

    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        _isMounted = true;
        try {
          await Audio.setAudioModeAsync({
            allowsRecordingIOS: false,
            interruptionModeIOS: Audio.INTERRUPTION_MODE_IOS_MIX_WITH_OTHERS,
            playsInSilentModeIOS: true,
            interruptionModeAndroid: Audio.INTERRUPTION_MODE_ANDROID_DUCK_OTHERS,
            shouldDuckAndroid: true,
            staysActiveInBackground: true, // https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/5472
            playThroughEarpieceAndroid: true
          })
          this.loadAudio()
        } catch (e) {
          console.log(e)
        }
      }

    async componentWillUnmount() {
        _isMounted = false;
        this.state.playbackInstance.unloadAsync();

    }

      async loadAudio() {
        const {currentIndex, isPlaying, volume} = this.state
        try {
          const playbackInstance = new Audio.Sound()
          const source = {
            uri: this.sets[this.state.index].audio_file
          }
          const status = {
            shouldPlay: isPlaying,
            volume
          }
          playbackInstance.setOnPlaybackStatusUpdate(this.onPlaybackStatusUpdate)
          await playbackInstance.loadAsync(source, status, false)
          this.setState({playbackInstance})
          } catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
          }
      }

      onPlaybackStatusUpdate = status => {
        this.setState({
          isBuffering: status.isBuffering
        })
      }

      handlePlayPause = async () => {
        const { isPlaying, playbackInstance } = this.state
        isPlaying
          ? await playbackInstance.pauseAsync()
          : await playbackInstance.playAsync()
        this.setState({
          isPlaying: !isPlaying
        })
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try {
    await this.state.playbackInstance.unloadAsync()
    await this.state.playbackInstance.loadAsync({uri: this.sets[this.state.index].audio_file});
    await this.state.playbackInstance.playAsync();
    await this.setState({
        isPlaying: true
      })
  } catch (err) {
    console.warn("Couldn't Play audio", err)
  }
```